# Selecting first radio button in ng-repeat, validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-ng-repeat

Angular1

I've used the index below to select the first value in the result set if it's not already selected.

See "**$index==0?true:false**" below

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="address in addresses | filter:vm.addressSearch">
<div class="checkbox">
    <input type="radio" name="address-list" id="address-{{address.addressId}}"
        ng-click="vm.setAddress( address.addressId )"
        ng-checked="address.addressId === vm.cart.addressId || $index==0?true:false">
</div>
```

JS Validation

```
vm.setAddress = function( addressId ) {
        vm.cart.addressId = addressId;
        updateShippingValid();
};

function updateShippingValid() {
        vm.shippingValid = angular.isNumber( vm.cart.addressId ) && ( vm.cart.addressId !== 0 ) && angular.isString( vm.cart.shipMethod );
}
```

Now the first addresses radio button will be selected on load, but my validation does not detect it as selected, it has to be clicked again to go through.

Is there a reason for this?

Thanks

Comment: ngChecked works only for user interaction.. You need to use nginit or initalize the value within controller... A different approach would be to use ngModel but that would mean not to use ngChecked

Answer (score 1):

At first, your `vm.cart.addressId` is undefined!

Only when you click on a radio button will it be set! Because of your `ng-click`.

That's why, you should initialize it at the beginning of your controller like this:

```
vm.cart.addressId = addresses[0].addressId;
```

Hope it helps